# Trying to display html in Github docs, and it just shows as raw text

Tags: github, github-pages

Trying to display html in Github docs, but it just shows as raw text.  Ideally, I'd like to make Readme use html, but it looks like I have to use Github pages, but that doesn't seem to help!

TIA

Comment: Let's show your source code. GitHub pages can display correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had created a repo called username/username.github.io, then realized that this was wrong, so I deleted it.  I then went into Settings on my Github master repo, set source to my docs directory, and magically the file showed up in https://username.github.io/repo, *formatted correctly*!  So, I think I can close this query!